# can i change the size of my thumbnails in the thumbnail browse list?

Tags: texturing

my textures are a bit complex sometimes and the small thumbnails can not show me enough details to make me decide which texture i want to choose .
 is there a way i can increase the size of the thumbnails when i want to replace a texture for an object ?
i looked around everywhere but i can not find an option to do this .
in mac osx i can increase a thumbnail view , that comes very handy most of the time. i would like to be able to do this in Blender. 
i don't mean to zoom in on the screen , that will result in a pixelated view. 
but a real increase of the thumbnail size while browsing in the thumbnail list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there no option to do this currently.

---

However there is a patch in the tracker to support this: https://developer.blender.org/T27830
*(It's not expected you should make your own patched Blender builds, just noting that it may well be supported soon)*

Comment: fair enough, but i hope there will be a future update in blender soon that has the option included in the browser,  instead of me checking out now how imported patches will work. for now i stay with the small sized thumbnails. thanks for a fast reply.